# Is it legal to put $\tan$ on both sides of the equation?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have this equation and I need to find $x$ variable:

$$1+\frac{\pi}{4}-x=\arctan x$$

can I put $\tan$ on RHS and LHS in order to find $x$:

$$\tan( 1+\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=\tan(\arctan x)$$

Secondly, after I have $x$ on RHS, how am I supposed to find $x$ if the LHS has now become a complicated expression?

Comment: Applying a function equally to both sides of an equation is always “legal”.

Comment: **implementable

Comment: I'm afraid that the law forbids putting people in the sun

Comment: @abiessu: But if it's a periodic function, the resulting equation might have solutions that the original equation didn't.  (Michael's answer already makes this point.)  The extreme case is multiplying both sides by `0`, which discards most of the information from the original equation.

Comment: IANAL, but it may depend on the jurisdiction. Please add more details.

Answer (score 10):

It is certainly true that **if** $1+\dfrac\pi4-x=\arctan x$ **then** $\tan\left(1+\dfrac\pi4-x\right)=\tan(\arctan x).$

But it is not true that **if** $\tan\left(1+\dfrac\pi4-x\right)=\tan(\arctan x)$ **then** $1+\dfrac\pi4-x=\arctan x,$ since $\tan$ is not a one-to-one function.

In other words, some of the solutions of the latter equation are not solutions of the former, so you'll need to check for extraneous roots.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct, but don't think this is a good strategy. Instead consider the  function
$$f(x)=\arctan x+x-1-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
and show that $x=1$ is the unique zero. Try to prove that $f$ is strictly increasing by considering its derivative, or just noting that  $f$ is the sum of $\arctan x$ and $x$ (which are strictly increasing) plus a constant. This is more a calculus problem than a trigonometry one!

Comment: Considering the derivative is an overkill here since $f(x)$ is just a sum of two clearly increasing functions and a constant.

Comment: @Adayah Yes, I agree with you. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

One obvious solution is following: **x = 1**.

If you plot the graphs of both functions:
$$f(x) = 1+\frac{\pi}{4}-x$$
and
$$f(x) = \arctan x$$
then it will be obvious, that except **x = 1** there are no other solutions. This is the only point where intersection is possible.

For any arbitrary constants there is no analytical solution. Instead, solutions are based on some iterating converging process until you reach needed precision.

Yes, it is legal to apply *tan* to both parts. When two values are equal, then their *tan* values are equal, too. But if you are going to use that to get an equation that is easier to solve, pay attention, because another equation can have *more* solutions than your original equation and you will have to *filter* them to find out the solution of your *original* equation.